# Swift Open Dialog closes

Tags: cocoa, swift

Is there a event in swift for when a "Open" Dialog disappears? I need to update my viewController when this happens. I am having a hard time correlating the "Open" in appDelegate to anything on the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the Open dialog? Are you using the NSOpenPanel?

If so, you can just update your view after the call to run the NSOpenPanel (with runModal())

Comment: The problem is I am trying to call a function in ViewController from a separate class that opens NSOpenPanel.